# weird > thing when compiling for sdl2 in g++

Tags: c++, g++, sdl-2

when ever I try to compile my window sample

```
g++ window.cpp `sdl-config --cflags --libs`
```

it outputs with this

```
 g++ window.cpp `sdl-config --cflags --libs
>
```

I tried removing the -o [output filename] (the command I showed), but it did not work either way.

Comment: Try running `sdl-config --cflags --libs` on its own and see what happens. It kinda looks like something is prompting you for input.

Comment: Are the `\`` supposed to be there?

Comment: @ChrisMM Yes, the shell replaces backticks by the output of the command, and `sdl-config` is designed to print options to be passed to the compiler. `g++ window.cpp $(sdl-config --cflags --libs)` is equivalent and arguably better (unless you're using csh or tcsh, which don't support it).

Comment: Are you typing that command at a shell prompt? What shell are you using?  I realize I'm assuming you're using a Unix-like shell; if you're on Windows using `cmd` or PowerShell, that's not going to work.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to paste the second quote?